# Windows Server - create firewall rules from network trace?

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-firewall, network-traffic

A good basis for firewall rules would be Zero Trust - only allow what is needed.
But in many cases, you do not know all the needed rules for a server connection. As a result in many evironments, the windows firewall is either disabled or poorly managed

I was thinking that maybe this would be a helpful approach:

1. Install a Windows server with all the needed applications. It is a test setup or you have a snapshot
2. allow everything
3. begin working and trace connections
4. from the connection trace, create firewall rules - I would prefer powershell commands / script
5. examine the script carefully
6. maybe apply some commonly known rules (like Ping / ICMP, AD Rules, ...) Most should be managed via GPO / from template
7. create a new server or revert to snapshot
8. apply the firewall rules you traced before. These will be the only allowed rules
9. deny everything else --> Zero Trust
10. further needed rules are upon failure or request

Does this make sense?

If yes, I would not know how to best capture the traffic and create rules / a script upon it

can anyone help me out?

thanks!

Comment: How would a script determine if a port that is currently used, should be allowed or not allowed? Think SSH admin access. Windows Firewall logging also just does not work in my experience. We had multiple instances where something was blocked, but nothing was written to the logfile. I could not find out why.

Comment: Maybe look into https://github.com/Microsoft/AaronLocker to help, get familiar with the logs, parse with Powershell to help narrow down. The OS level firewall is just an extra huddle to put in the way to be knocked down before allowing access to a system. You could also use OS level application execution allow/white listing, have your system(s) isolated and segregated on your local network(s), have machine admin credential locked down in place. If you use any FW logging for "learn mode" I suggest ensuring logging is enabled for all ALLOW rules, make some traffic, get familiar with logs.

Comment: @DavidTrevor - Thx. The script should not determine if it should or not. It should just trace if it was used and list. from the list, generate a script. Maybe I am spelling it misleading.
Regarding FW logging in Windows - there is a bug, that the FW sometimes has not enough write permission to the default folder. Set a temp folder (C:\temp) and it will work.